# I'm trying to insert data with contentValues to my sqlite database with android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
public long insertNewUserData(String name, String address, String email, String password){
        ContentValues initialValuesOfUserTable = new ContentValues();
        initialValuesOfUserTable.put("Name",name);
        initialValuesOfUserTable.put("Address",address);
        initialValuesOfUserTable.put("email",email);
        initialValuesOfUserTable.put("Password",password);
        return myDataBase.insert("User", null, initialValuesOfUserTable);

    }
```

My problem is cant insert data to my sqlite database. It is connected and can get data but cant insert.

Comment: Your code is not formatted, and you haven't really told us what your problem is.

Comment: you need to add the logcat trace.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method:

```
public Long insert_todoinfo(String a, String b, String c, String d,
            String e, String f, String g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues con = new ContentValues();
        con.put("title", a);
        con.put("description", b);
        con.put("category", e);
        con.put("due_date", c);
        con.put("alarm_time", d);
        con.put("alarm_set", f);
        con.put("priority", g);
        con.put("parform", "false");
        mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_TODO_LIST, null, con);
```

Comment: frist see you db is created in SD-card

Answer (score 1):

Ckeck the database file permissions via DDMS, make sure your are not attempt to write a readonly database

Answer (score 0):

```
if(db!=null){
         ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
         row.put("rt_id",tid);
         row.put("rs_id", sid);
         row.put("rsubject", rsubject);
         row.put("rdescr",rdescr);
         row.put("day", day);
         row.put("month",month);
         row.put("year",year);
         row.put("stamp", stamp);
         row.put("amount",amount);

         long chk = db.insert("records",null, row);

         if(chk!=0){
             Toast.makeText(myContext, "Record added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
         }else{
             Toast.makeText(myContext, "Record added failed...! ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
       }else{
           Toast.makeText(myContext, "could Not connected database..!!! ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
       }
     }catch(SQLiteException exc){
         Toast.makeText(myContext, "Record could not saved...!!! ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }finally{
         db.close();
         }
```

Here db is SQLiteDatabase object and initialize it by getting getWritableDatabase() from DbHelper class. But if you got NullPointerException then you should check it,if whether it is null or not. Happy Android programming..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public long insertNewUserData(String name, String address, String email, String password){

        myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("databasename.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null)
        ContentValues initialValuesOfUserTable = new ContentValues();
        initialValuesOfUserTable.put("Name",name);
        initialValuesOfUserTable.put("Address",address);
        initialValuesOfUserTable.put("email",email);
        initialValuesOfUserTable.put("Password",password);
        return myDataBase.insert("User", null, initialValuesOfUserTable);

    }
```